# Подключение в maven сторонней библиотеки

Tags: java

Вопрос, хочу добавить .jar библиотеку к maven проекту, чтобы потом jenkins собирался нормально.

Соответсвенно 2 вопроса:

1. Читал статью https://habrahabr.ru/company/lanit/blog/323008/
   maven скомпилировал, в pom.xml dependecy прописал, не совсем понял момент:

   > Дать проекту знать, что репозиторий существует, и показать, где он
   >   находится, можно уже описанным способом, правда, с поправкой на то,
   >   что репозиторий локальный.
   >
   > ```
   > <repositories>
   >     <repository>
   >         <id>localrep</id>
   >         <name>local repository</name>
   >         <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
   >     </repository> 
   > </repositories>
   > ```

   Можете пожалуйста подсказать, на примере, что здесь написать - вроде сейчас работает, но поиск, как я понимаю, делает на компьютере с jenkins , т.е. в `file:${project.basedir}` мы указываем путь на локалку используемого компьютера.
   Как сделать чтобы он закачивал с другого компа?
2. И отсюда вытекает второй вопрос - если нужна открытая для внутренней локалки папка с "репозиторием", ее можно расшарить и указать в `<url></url>` ?

Comment: Есть еще сайт http://doduck.com/adding-local-jar-in-maven-local-repository/, и там нижний пример как я понимаю направлен чтобы прям вообще из проекта мавен забирал библиотеку, правильно понимаю?
Только у меня в pom.xml путь указанный через / (слеши) , красный. Я неправильно указываю или что не так? (Через слеши путь пиши, прям как в примере только в своем проекте)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед ответом хочу сказать, что единственное решение противоречит идеологии *maven*. Правильным решением будет установка твоей библиотеки в удаленный maven-репозиторий (возможно корпоративный/закрытый), что делается при помощи команды `deploy`.

А теперь о неправильном, но рабочем решении. В корне проекта, т.е. на одном уровне с папкой *src* создаешь папку (в примере это *lib*), в которую будут складироваться *локальные* библиотеки. Кладешь туда нужный тебе jar'ник. Далее делаешь *dependecy* со *scope* `system`. Примерно так

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.stackoverflow.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>megalib</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/megalib.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Но тут есть два нюанса.

1. Указанный *scope* официально объявлен как **устаревший**.
2. Если в pom'нике есть хоть одна зависимость со *scope* как `system`, то этот проект не будет добавлять в **зависимые от него** проекты транзистивные зависимости.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало!
Касательно вашего ответа, можно уточнить: 
1. Не надо использовать  - т.к. в случае обновлений, надо будет заново все дописывать - и главное чтобы нигде не допустить ошибку, иначе просто и не запустится jenkins?

2. Я так понимаю что для таких целей используют Nexus(https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype) . 
Подскажите туториал? + Его лучше ставить на тот же компьютер где и jenkins?

Comment: @sank 1. Не понял вопрос. 2. Самый популярный - nexus, другие перечислены [здесь](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html). Годные руководства на русском не скажу, т.к. сам когда-то ставил только с [официального](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Installation).

Comment: да я просто уточнял почему не правильно все в ручную писать. Спасибо, буду смотреть!

Answer (score 1):

выше предложенный вариант со скоупом систем имеет место быть, но ничто не мешает любую библиотеку инсталлировать в локальный репозитарии с реальными groupId, artifactId, version или выдуманными.. для вышеприведенного артефакта (с выдуманной версией 1.0.0) команда в консоли будет выглядеть так

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=ru.stackoverflow.com -DartifactId=megalib -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=megalib.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

разумеется, чтобы это правильно отработало нужно, чтобы в path был прописан путь до maven'а и запускать нужно из того каталога, где находится megalib.jar

затем в pom файл вставляем зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.stackoverflow.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>megalib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.</version> 
</dependency>
```

и наслаждаемся

Comment: Да, делал также как в статье, не разобрался только как правильно писать путь. Но спасибо за ответ.